# Edit Swipe in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swipe, swipe-gesture

I need to swipe like a book using swipe function, how i can edit this? because only effect is partial Curl but it swipes like up but i need horizontal this is the code- what i need to change?

```
let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipeAction(swipe:)))
leftSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
```

...

```
func swipeAction(swipe:UISwipeGestureRecognizer)
{

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goRight", sender: self)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using UIPageViewController?

Comment: What you mean? I tried to edit transition Style even in a view controller
I need swipe like this not like in a based application because i want to work with multiple things in one viewcontroller